# Android WebView Cache lost after activity closed

Tags: android, caching, webview

While I'm navigating inside WebView caching work fine, after once I closed WebActivity and launch again it loaded all resources again.

```
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webSettings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    webSettings.builtInZoomControls = true
    webSettings.displayZoomControls = false
    webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
    webSettings.allowFileAccess = true
    webSettings.cacheMode = LOAD_DEFAULT
```

I go through various solution available on stackoverfolw but not get any of them worked. I'm not using `clearCache()`.

Can anyone please help me on how to resolve this issue?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
webSettings.clearCache(false);
```

might be workful for you !

Comment: Tried, Not worked